# Building graph from binary matrix

Tags: python, matrix, graph, igraph

I am trying to use `igraph` to create graphs from binary matrixes, but I am having this error:

```
NameError: name 'graph_from_adjacency_matrix' is not defined
```

I have downloaded python_igraph. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example how this can be done:

```
import igraph as ig
import numpy as np
g = ig.Graph.Adjacency(np.array([[False, True,  False, False],
                [False, False, True,  False],
                [True,  False, False, True ],
                [False, False, True,  False]]).tolist())
g.vs['label'] = ['A','B','C','D']
ig.plot(g,  
        bbox = (200, 100), # bounding box of plot
        vertex_color='lightgreen',
        layout=g.layout('circle'), 
        vertex_label=g.vs['label'],
        vertex_frame_width=3)
```

[image]

You might also need to download `pycairo` from unofficial binaries to unlock `plot` option.